# Cannot get onto sqlitestudio.pl to install sqlite studio, got error: err: database or disk is full

Tags: sqlite, installation, sqlitestudio

I am trying to install sqlite studio and from what I have researched I have seen that I need to go to sqlitestudio.pl. However, once I navigate to the website I get an error saying: err: database or disk is full
I have downloaded the sqlite3tools and have done nothing at all with them. I have tried searching up the error to see if anyone else had the same issue as me but I have not found anything like I am experiencing. Usually, others have gotten this error using the database but as I mentioned above I have only just downloaded the tools from the sqlite official website. Does anyone know what could be the issue at hand here and could help me? I do not necessarily need sqlite studio but the GUI will be very helpful. Thank you so much ahead of time.

**EDIT** : So I just decided to download another tool, DBeaver as it supports SQLite and other RDB's as well so it will suit my needs. Will not mark this as solved yet just in case someone does know why this is happening and could help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting server was indeed full. It is resolved now. Regardless of that, you can always reach binaries to download at GitHub releases: https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/releases